# Python - How do I get classes that rely on each other to be defined in the same file?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following code used in Django:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


# Create your models here.

class User(AbstractUser):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(group)

class group(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="course", null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I made this code to get a user model in django that allows for more fields. However, the new user class requires the group field since a user can join many groups. This is causing an error since the group is defined after class. What do I do to fix this issue? What I really need is just a way to add extra fields to the default User class so I tried it like so from another SE post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can to put quotes around the word "group" in the definition of the User model field:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField('group')
```

Comment: This ^. And please capitalise your class names.